# CMake boost imported targets

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Can you explain me how should I use something like `Boost::headers` in my CMake file? I tried to utilize it somehow but is seems to work in different manner than I understand it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(Test)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS asio REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test SYSTEM PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC Boost::headers)
```

This example does not work. It is caused by `COMPONENTS asio`. ASIO seems to be treated in other way because it is header only library.

Documentation says:

> Boost::[C] - Target for specific component dependency (shared or static library)
>
> [C] is lower-case

I can agree that ASIO may not be library in the terms of CMake's definition. Documentation emphasises that it must be either static or shared library. ASIO is header only so it is just a file to be included.

So let's try to use it in another way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(Test)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test SYSTEM PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC Boost::headers)
```

Right now I am assuming that if CMake managed to find Boost, ASIO will be present. It is possible to perform configuration step, but when I try to build whole project it turns out that I am missing some dependencies. Boost::headers seems to be somehow unnecessary.

Unfortunately CMake's documentation is not the best I have ever seen. It is hard to get any information related with more complicated things.

Answer (score 7):

The target to include the Boost headers is named `Boost::boost` not `Boost::headers`.

If you use that, you don't need `target_include_directories(... ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` (note the `S` at the end of the variable). `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` without `S` is used in find_package to lookup the header files.

Boost::asio is a header only library and CMakes FindBoost.cmake module does not create targets for header only libraries.
When dealing with `Boost::asio` you need to add `system` and `thread` to your required modules in find_package and add `Boost::thread` and `Boost::system` to your target_link_libraries call. See https://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio.html for a good explanation.

So your CMakeLists.txt would look like follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(Test)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC Boost::boost Boost::system Boost::thread)
```

**Edit**: Boost::headers was introduced in CMake 3.15 and Boost::boost is now an alias to it.

Comment: According to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html `Boost::headers` is an alias. So it should work. Besides, when I want to use for instance Boost.Filesystem, I can `find_package(... filesystem)` and then I can link `Boost::filesystem` to my main target. It should handle all dependecies. I want to do the same thing with ASIO.

Comment: The `Boost::headers` target has been added with CMake 3.15 recently, I was not aware of that. AFAIK no targets are created in FindBoost module for header only libraries. So you either create a target on your own and populate all necessary properties or you add the dependencies manually.

Comment: So what is the actual purpose of adding Boost::boost to target_link_libraries?

Comment: In case you have header only Boost libraries without further dependencies you should add the target Boost::boost (or Boost headers) to the target_link_librares call. As most Boost libraries are header only and do not have additional library dependencies this case is quite common. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries for a list of non header only libraries. Good examples are Boost/Any or Boost/Array

Comment: But why should one link against a header file? I cannot find anything about what this target does in general. Seems to does nothing at all.

Comment: A target combines properties for linker, compiler, and other tools. So it might have set a property containing the include path, another property containing the name of the library for build type Release, another one for build type Debug. Additionally properties may be set for compiler definitions and switches, for linker switches, ... So a target combines all that stuff in a single name. CMake will correctly propagate the settings to the tools is use. All you have to do is adding the target to the target_link_libraries call.