# Android build using CMake not able to locate external C++ library files

Tags: android, boost, cmake

I am trying to use the pre-compiled boost from [silverglint](http://silverglint.com/boost-for-android/). 
For some reason, the build system is not able to locate source files [**these files are present in src/main/cpp/boost/**]

```
.../app/src/main/cpp/boost/thread.hpp:13:10: fatal error: 'boost/thread/thread.hpp' file not found
```

Following is the relevant content of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(boost SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET boost PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../libs/arm64-v8a/libboost_thread.so
        )

include_directories(
        src/main/cpp/boost/
        )
```

I suspect this is error is due to misconfigured path. Any help in resolving this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is included at the path:

```
boost/thread/thread.hpp
```

and the file is actually located here:

```
src/main/cpp/boost/thread/thread.hpp
```

I believe the included directory should be:

```
include_directories(
    src/main/cpp
)
```

As commented, it is best practice to use *absolute* paths when including directories in CMake. Also, prefer the target-specific [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) command whenever possible, to prevent the pollution of the global include directories space:

```
target_include_directories(YourTarget PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp
)
```

---

FWIW, the idiomatic way to import Boost libraries into your project is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58203391/3987854) answer, and is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: I tried the above and still getting the same error. I was able to get past using **"thread/thread.hpp"** instead of **<boost/thread/thread.hpp>** but then I have to change path in too many files and that is causing other problems!

Comment: The conventional way to include boost headers is like `#include <boost/thread.hpp>`, with each header being pre-pended with the `boost/` directory indicating that it is indeed a Boost include file, not one local to your project. Thus, including the `src/main/cpp` directory via CMake is the best approach. Otherwise, yes, you will have to change all the include paths in all the boost header files, which would be crazy!

Comment: Also Android-Studio complains about **angled includes** like <xyz.hpp>. Thus in my cpp source file I had to use **#include "boost/thread.hpp"** statement.

Comment: I suspect it will work if you instead do `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp)`. If that works, then you might as well change that to `target_include_directories(boost PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp)` instead.

Comment: @thomas_f Indeed I did something like that and it worked. Thanks you so much!  Can you please add rational behind the `target_include_directories(.., PUBLIC, ..)`. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @thomas_f Agreed, expanded the answer to include this. I also added a link to the documentation. Modern CMake prefers `target_include_directories()` over the old `include_directories()` command.

Comment: `include_directories` works on the directory level (meaning the current `CMakeLists.txt`). If you later do a `add_subdirectory(<path>)`, then any targets created from there will not have access  to those include folders. `target_include_directories` will propagate (assuming you specified PUBLIC or INTERFACE scope) to all dependent targets, meaning in this case that any targets linking to `boost` will also have access to its include, regardless of where the target was created. You should always prefer the `target_` family of functions. It also, as said, avoids polluting unrelated targets.